# Framework search path of a pod

Tags: ios, xcode, react-native, cocoapods

I started a React Native bridge module which is supposed to be installed through NPM. The module requires a specific SDK that must be added to the main project.
On iOS, the installation of the native part is managed by Cocoapod, but once the module is installed, I need to add `$(PROJECT_DIR)/../**` to `Framework Search Paths` of my module target in the pod project in order to make the pod find the SDK.
It would be nice if I could:

- define that path in the pod directly
  or
- automatically add that path after the pod installation

The main idea there would be to ease the setup of the module. Do you think something of that kind could be achieved ?

Thank you all